# jquery outside selector tag(class or id)

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

html :

```
<td>
   <input type="text" name="c_name[]" class="form-control cast-name" id="cast1" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="cast-search">
       <div class="cast-pop">
          <ul>  
            <li class="item">1</li>
            <li class="item">2</li>
            <li class="item">3</li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" name="c_name[]" class="form-control cast-name" id="cast2" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="cast-search">
       <div class="cast-pop">
          <ul>  
            <li class="item">1</li>
            <li class="item">2</li>
            <li class="item">3</li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Take the any 'li' value. outside their "input" I would like to print

```
$('body').on('keyup','.cast-name',function(){
        $(this).next().slideDown(200);
        var datas = $(this).val();
        var cast_pop = document.getElementsByClassName('cast-pop');
        $.ajax({
            url:"include/film/cast_get.php",
            type:"GET",
            data:'cast='+datas,
            success:function(answer){
                $('.cast-pop').html(answer);
                $('.item').click(function(){
                    // how will I do ... 
               }
            }
        });
    });
```

When i click one of the "li" elements, i can get the value with alert() function. But what i want is to getting this value to input

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify what the problem is and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: FYI, this is invalid HTML markup, `li` can only be direct child of `ul/ol` or `template` elements

Comment: @A.Wolff ok .I change it . So how do I do now

Comment: @vulkan I'm sorry but i still have no idea what you are looking for. `Take the any 'li' value. outside their "input" I would like to print` What does mean?

Comment: Ok maybe you want: `$('.cast-pop').html(answer).find('.item').click(function(){ $('#cast1').val(this.innerHTML);});`  and better delegate event as suggested in answer below

Comment: @A.Wolff When i click one of the "li" elements, i can get the value with alert() function. But what i want is to getting this value to input

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').click(function(){
                    // how will I do ... 
               }
```

I think you want to know how to get the click event for the dynamically created `.item` `li` in your ajax call.

You need to read about **.delegate()**

> **Description**: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a
>   specific set of root elements.

```
$( document ).on( "li", "click", function() {
  // you do like this
});
```

But no need to write the above code in ajax success. You can write outside your ajax call.

Comment: When i click one of the "li" elements, i can get the value with alert() function. But what i want is to getting this value to input